# Reference to local variable '...' returned from object initializer

Tags: c++, function

I am trying to overload operators to add PPM images together, creating a new image. However, When trying to make a new object in the function,

```
PPM& PPM::operator*(const double& rhs) const {
     int height = this->getHeight();
     int width = this-> getWidth();
     int mc = this-> getMaxColorValue();
     PPM lhs;
     // ...
     return lhs;
}
```

And there's a bunch of other stuff, ending with `return(lhs);` When I try to compile the code, I get an error saying:

```
error: reference to local variable 'lhs' returned [-Werror=return-local-addr] PPM lhs;
```

What is going wrong?

Comment: Is there any reason that you chose the return type as `PPM&` instead of `PPM`?

Comment: Returning a reference to `lhs` would lead to a dangling reference, as it goes out of scope

Comment: The error is describing exactly what is going wrong: you create a temporary variable inside the function, named `lhs`. When you return a reference to `lhs`, the initial object will be deleted, so the reference will be junk, and so the compiler will warn you about it. You need to return by-value.

Comment: I was given the assignment in a class, and was told that the return type needed to be `PPM&`

Comment: @Fading3clipse That would be very unusual for `operator*`. `operator*=` usually returns a reference, but `operator*` usually returns by value. I don't know how returning a reference would make sense here.

Comment: @Fading3clipse Well, then you might want to pre-compute the value of lhs in the constructor of the object, so you can return a reference to a class variable. That's still highly unusual, however, since you're not supposed to return by-reference for `operator*`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`PPM lhs;` is local to the function and you cannot return a reference to a local variable.
`lhs` will die at the end of the function and you will have a dangling reference an if it compile you enter undefined behavior land.

Comment: How would I go about returning the actual object or value of the object?

Comment: @Fading3clipse if you want to return by value just remove & from function return type.

Comment: That worked, and now that I look back at the assignment, I see that I was accidentally adding the & to the return, so thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your `operator*` is a member function. When called like this:

```
some_ppm * 1.2
```

Here, `1.2` is your `double rhs`.

But what is your `lhs`?

Looking at your function, the left hand side is ***not*** `some_ppm`. Take a look:

```
PPM& PPM::operator*(const double& rhs) const {
     // ...
     PPM lhs;
     // ...
     return lhs;
}
```

In this case, `lhs` is alway a *local*, *new instance* of a `PPM`.

So where is the *real* `rhs`?

Rember that when you called an overloaded operator, you effectively call the member function:

```
some_ppm.operator*(1.2) // actually well formed syntax
```

And yes you guessed it, it's `this`. And your operator should not return a reference to the `PPM`, but should instead do just like a `double` or an `int` or even a `std::string` and return a *copy*:

```
//v----- return by value
PPM PPM::operator*(const double& rhs) const {
    int height = this->getHeight();
    int width = this-> getWidth();
    int mc = this-> getMaxColorValue();
    PPM result;

    // ...

    return result;
}
```